Repeat python function with precise time stamp
I have a task to communicate with a hardware with reasonably high precision (1pps) to simulate telemetry data collection. Based on StackOverflow and other sources I was able to come up with the following code.
The code works good enough, however it has a runoff with about 1 msec. I.E., the beginning every execution is late by about 1 millisecond. If left running overnight, the runoff increases to several dozen millisec. The real hardware host has a GPS source for 1pps, but I need to test my hardware with simulation from the PC.
The printout chart is the best way to understand the problem.
The plotting is optional, but it shows the problem visually.
Questions:
What is the source of the constant delay?
Is there a way to force synchronize Time to NTP?
Is there a way to access the System clock instead of Python Time?
All good critique is welcome!
Here is the code:
# 1pps Project
# IVR Labs, Inc.
#____V0.54_______
import threading
from datetime import *
import time
from tkinter import *

global last_time
Xpos = 10
Xposl = 10
Yposl = 255


class Timer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self._timer_runs = threading.Event()
        self._timer_runs.set()
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        while self._timer_runs.is_set():
            self.my_timer()
            time.sleep(_1PPS.interval)

    def stop(self):
        self._timer_runs.clear()

    def my_timer(self):
        pass


class _1PPS(Timer):
    interval = 1   # Interval in seconds.

    # Function to be executed.
    def my_timer(self):
        global last_time
        global Xpos, Xposl, Yposl
        timestamp = datetime.now(timezone.utc)  # - timestamp
        usec = timestamp.microsecond
        time_delta = usec-last_time.microsecond
        # plotvalue = datetime.now(timezone.utc).microsecond - timestamp.microsecond
        print(timestamp, (timestamp-last_time), time_delta)
        last_time = timestamp
        if Xpos >= 1280:
            Xpos = 10
        else:
            Xpos = Xpos + 1
        Ypos = time_delta/10
        if Ypos > 480:
            Ypos = 255
        plot.create_rectangle(Xpos, 11, Xpos+2, 489, width=0, fill='white smoke')
        plot.create_line(Xposl, Yposl, Xpos, Ypos, fill='red')
        Xposl = Xpos
        Yposl = Ypos


win = Tk()
win.geometry('1280x520')
plot = Canvas(win, width=1280, height=500)
plot.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="ne")
plot.create_line(9, 9, 9, 1270, fill='blue')
plot.create_line(0, 490, 1270, 490, fill='blue')

_1PPS = _1PPS()
last_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
_1PPS.start()

win.mainloop()

_1PPS.stop()



UPD:
The internal clock might be more or less stable, but Python gets interrupted by other processes, and that adds unpredictable delays, that ruin the whole process. I was able to get much more accurate 1pps from USB-UART GPS receiver, setting it to transmit only ZDA and processing pySerial events.


since Python uses your system clock, NTP sync depends on your OS configuration. Actually, that "step" in the plotted data looks like an NTP sync event to me. For timing, you might want to look at clock_gettime_ns. But keep in mind that this is all OS-dependent; results may vary between different platforms (Windows, Linux etc.).

If you want exact timing, you need realtime hardware. However, you can correct for the drift. Take the actual current time, and compute how long to sleep to reach the next target time. Yes, it can always be a little off, but it won't accumulate more drift.

Thank you for the replies!
FObersteiner, unfortunately ._ns is available only in Linux, as you have warned.
@Kenny, thank you for the hint! Once the sleep time was turned into a variable, (1sec-runtime), I get similar variations, but they are not cumulative, i.e. there is no run-off.
